# How to store file paths, which collation to use?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqlite

I have a table that stores Windows system paths. I am scratching my head about how to store them and in particular which collation to use.

The paths are unicode strings. They are case insensitive, therefore 'utf8_bin`is probably not the best thing to do. However all the`utf8_*_ci` collations allows equality between strings corresponding to different paths.

I am aware that path comparison is generally much more involved that string comparison, due to the potential presence of parent (`..`) directories, symbolic links, 8.3 alternative naming, aso. I am assuming that the folders are input in a systematically consistent fashion.

What do people do when storing paths? Do they assume that folders are indeed always stored in a consistent fashion and say always store Windows paths in lower or upper case and use `utf8_general`? Or another collation? Or simply forget about the idea of using server-side path comparison?

Comment: Look for `character_set_filesystem` variable value. *However all the `utf8_*_ci` collations allows equality between strings corresponding to different paths.* This depends of OS file requestor settings. And it may use collation unknows to MySQL.

Comment: Please give an example of where "theutf8_*_ci` collations allows equality between strings corresponding to different paths"

Comment: Be aware that backslash is, _in some contexts_, an escape character, not a path delimiter.

Comment: Are you storing full paths?  Or storing directory names, plus "parent", etc to build a hierarchical tree?

Comment: @RickJames I am stocking full paths. "utf8_*_ci" would not work because "a" and "à" would be considered a match although there can be two distinct directories with those names.

Comment: @user209974 - The `_ci` means "case insensitive", and also "accent insensitive".  So, "a" and "à" are considered to be equal.  If you need them to be unequal, use `utf8_bin`.

Comment: @RickJames Windows paths are case insensitive, but accent sensitive, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not until MySQL 8.0 is there a "case-insensitive, accent-sensitive" collation:

```
mysql> set names utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'a'='A', "a" = "à" ;
+---------+------------+
| 'a'='A' | "a" = "à"  |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          0 |
+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent in MariaDB, although I found this [blog post about adding a custom collation](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/adding-a-case-insensitive-distinct-unicode-collation) -- I am not sure I want to go through all this trouble though.

Comment: @user209974 - You could also file a bug with jira.mariadb.com